# ChartControl: how to disable axis labels when no related series points?

Tags: devexpress

Take a look at the screenshot: there are a few labels on both axis even though there is no related chart points. Can i configure chart control to show labels only when there is some data on chart (see second picture)?

Actual

[image: ACTUAL]

Desired

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the label with a specific axis value then you should handle the [ChartControl.CustomDrawAxisLabel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/DevExpressXtraChartsChartControl_CustomDrawAxisLabeltopic) event.  Please refer to the sample code snippet in the CustomDrawAxisLabel documentation article.

```
private void chartControl1_CustomDrawAxisLabel(object sender, CustomDrawAxisLabelEventArgs e)
        {
            AxisBase axis = e.Item.Axis;
            if (axis is AxisY || axis is AxisY3D || axis is RadarAxisY)
            {
                //Put your condition at below two lines..
                double axisValue = (double)e.Item.AxisValue;
                if (axisValue == 0)
                {
                    e.Item.Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
```

Refer these for more information with change of point values:
[Conditionally change a chart axis label not based on axis value](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T276086)

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. Pretty strange way to customize labels but anyway. Can you also suggest correct way to "extract" year value? What i want is to display year once for all labels when all points are from the same year?

Comment: in case if you are using datetime scale then your e.Item.AxisValue will be a datetime value so you can get  `((DateTime)e.Item.AxisValue).Year`. I am not much sure but you can check it once.

Comment: No problem with retrieving of value itself. I don't know where to place it actually. Do i need any additional label? Can i somehow display second line of labels below first one?

Comment: i am not sure about the second level. May be it is not possible as i have discovered these controls. you can ask devexpress guys with support ticket. they can better answer this question.